# how to log the response and request in API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

how to log the response size ,request size, error message from API management instance? 
If yes then how can I fetch the data from it.

Comment: Here is a complete walkthrough on logging request/response details in APIM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-log-to-eventhub-sample

Comment: Thanks for the reply.One thing i want to ask how can i log the api time(response time) for each request.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inbuilt "log-to-event-hub" policy that you can use to send basically any information that exists on the context object (meaning the request/response + a bit more) to an event hub. From there you can use any regular method for processing the events

How to log events to [Azure Event Hubs in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i want to write the api time into my table thorough policies.can u help me on this?

Comment: @soumyaranjanpanda
You can use C# expressions to get the DateTime, and you can write it into HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1):

Use Azure Monitor to configure [diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-of-diagnostic-logs) from ApiManagement to either Storage, Eventhub or Log Analytics. These logs have the data you are looking for.

I would start with free tier of Log Analytics for easy querying, dashboards and alerting. Refer [this](https://trello.com/c/NAXjjVrQ/39-azure-monitor-integration).

For more custom logging, you can use log to event hub policy. Refer this [blog](https://blog.mexia.com.au/monitor-your-azure-api-management-instance-with-powerbi).